# Rails Collection that does not contain new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I am setting up a new record, and a collection of records. How can I eliminate the new_record from the collection?

```
def index
  @note = @user.notes.build
  @notes = @user.notes
end
```

Unfortunately I am getting an empty Note record when I don't desire it.

**Update**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_user

  def index
    prepare_notes
  end

  private

  def prepare_notes
    @notes = @user.notes
    @note = @user.notes.build
  end

  def get_user
    @user = current_user
  end

end
```

Comment: When you render out @notes, you can `@notes.select(&:persisted?).each`

Comment: I've thought about that, but that just doesn't seem very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building the empty record here: `@note = @user.notes.build`

When you call `@user.notes` in either of the two lines, AR is caching the resulting collection. So in both lines of code, it is returning the same collection object. When the `build` method is called, the new empty `Note` object is added to this same collection. Thus, it doesn't matter what order you put those lines of code in, you will always see the new empty `Note`.

If you have the relation setup both ways, you can create a new note and assign the user to it:

```
def index
  @note = Note.new(user: @user)
  @notes = @user.notes
end
```

This creates a new `Note` and sets up it's internal user reference. However, it does not modify the user object with this association yet.

If you are not going to use the `@note.user` reference in your view, you can drop the attachment to the user and just have `@note = Note.new`. Depending on if you allow users to create notes for other users, your `#create` action can set the user at that point.

Comment: I guess what I could do is just do `@note = Note.new` and then assign it to the user in the `create` action. What you're saying does work, but what I don't understand is why reversing the order (like @Paulo Fidalgo mentioned) does not.

Comment: @ardavis I stated that in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Ahh yes, I apologize, I misunderstood after I read it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveResource/Base/build/class) it creates a new empty object. If you change the order of the lines:

```
def index
  @notes = @user.notes
  @note = @user.notes.build
end
```

in the @notes variable you'll get the actual notes.

Comment: I've totally tried this, and somehow, my @notes is still showing an empty note... let me double check and see what's going on.

Comment: I've added my controller code. Somehow `@notes` is showing up as: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Note id: nil, content: nil, author_id: 2, project_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, publisher_id: nil>]>`